# string "Fri Dec 16 16:12:24 CST 2016" to timestamp by shell

Tags: shell

I have some string (read from a file) ,such as "Fri Dec 16 16:12:24 CST 2016", and How to convert this string to timestamp, by shell?

> I need timestamp,such as `Fri Dec 16 16:27:28 CST 2016` -> `1481876854`

shell cmd `date` print `Fri Dec 16 16:12:24 CST 2016`,so I think `date` have some method to do it.

but I can't find a solution,Can someone help me?

macos 10.12.2

[image]

Comment: In which format do you want it to be printed? and do you have `GNU date`, let us know what is `date --version`?

Comment: I need `timestamp`,such as `Fri Dec 16 16:27:28 CST 2016` -> `1481876854`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `FreeBSD date`, you can use the `-j` flag with format as `-f` `"%a %b %d %T %Z %Y"`

```
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Fri Dec 16 16:27:28 CST 2016" +"%s"
1481876854
```

If you are using `GNU` based `date` command, you can convert to `EPOCH` timestamp using the `-d` flag, i.e.

```
date -d"Fri Dec 16 16:27:28 CST 2016" +%s
1481876854
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your spec (time format) and if `date` doesn't work or is not available, the heavy tool

```
echo "Fri Dec 16 16:27:28 CST 2016" \
 | gawk -F '[[:blank:]:]' 'BEGIN{
        split( "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Agu Sep Oct Nov Dec", Temp, " ")
        for (t in Temp) Month[ Temp[t]] = t < 10 ? "0" t : t
        }
    {
        # mktime assume ISO C time format: "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"
        ISOTime = sprintf( "%d %s %s %s %s %s\n", $8, Month[ $2], $3 < 10 ? "0" $3 : $3, $4, $5, $6)
        print mktime( ISOTime)
    }
    '
```

Comment: thank you help, and I think `date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Fri Dec 16 16:27:28 CST 2016" +"%s"` is a good way!!!